# how to run some code when one object dealloc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

There is a need to run some code when one object get dealloc. E.g, I set up one observer which updates the label A's text when object B's name changed.  When label A's retain count reach 0, I want to remove the observer from B.

Possible solutions:
1 Subclass and call the clean code in dealloc.

2 Create a wrapper class which able to run arbitrary code in dealloc and associate this object to label A. When A get dealloc, the associated object get dealloc too (suppose only A holds the strong ref to it), then the code get called.

I don't like the 1st one since it is so intrusive that makes it barely useless, need to subclass just for some easy stuff. So I am using No.2.

Do you have any comments? How do you do it?

Comment: It sounds like neither of those objects are controllers, usually a controller would perform that kind of role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my solution here in case someone needed.

```
@interface ExecuteWrapper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^block)();

-(void)dealloc;
@end

@implementation ExecuteWrapper
-(void)dealloc{
    if(self.block){
        self.block();
    }
}
@end

@implementation NSObject (SLUtil)

+(void)executeWhenDealloc:(NSObject *)object block:(void(^)())block{
    static char key;
    NSMutableArray *executeWrapperArray = [object associatedValueForKey:&key];
    if ( executeWrapperArray == nil){
        executeWrapperArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [object associateValue:executeWrapperArray withKey:&key];
    }
    ExecuteWrapper *executeWrapper = [[ExecuteWrapper alloc] init];
    executeWrapper.block = block;
    [executeWrapperArray addObject:executeWrapper];
}
@end
```

In client code

```
[NSObject executeWhenDealloc:labelA block:^{
    // clean up code
}];
```

Note: Keep in mind that don't hold a strong ref to label A in the label